# I need help understanding/solving this word problem.

Tags: percentages, word-problem

The question:

> A sample is marked as containing 27.3% calcium carbonate by mass (a) How many grams of calcium carbonate are contained in 64.33 grams of the sample? (b) How many grams of the sample would contain 11.4 grams of calcium carbonate?

I’m studying general chemistry however this is a question from chapter 1 of my book and like all sciences, chemistry uses mathematics and this question is more of a math orientated one.

I solved question ‘a’ which is 17.56g (please correct me if I am wrong) but I am having trouble figuring out a way to solve question ‘b’. From what I have read I need to find how many grams of the sample contain 11.4g of calcium carbonate.

> (b) How many grams of the sample would contain 11.4 grams of calcium carbonate?

Honestly I have no idea how to go about solving the question; so after many (failed) attempts of formulating a way to find the answer I decided to turn to this website for help, this is my first time here so I do not really know how things work here so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Write down the equality that led you to the answer $17.56$ for (a):

$$0.273\ \times\ 64.33=17.56209$$
Replace the answer by the stated goal in (b), and replace 64.33 with a question mark:
$$0.273\ \times\ ?=11.4$$
Can you solve this?